# Why study moment problem in one dimensional case?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, moment-problem

I have been reading about moment problem and I have been curious about the following question.

What is the motivation for studying the Hamburger moment problem(one dimensional moment problem?

I have been asking myself out of curiosity, what is gained by people who considered this case? or let me say how can  I explain my reasons to someone who has little knowledge about the subject the reasons for for studying hamburger moment problem.

I will be more than happy if useful literatures can be suggested or provided with some explanations.

Thanks for your useful suggestions and explanations

Answer (score 2):

> The importance of the moment problem is a consequence of the fact that it is at the crossroads of several branches and applications of mathematics. It relates to linear algebra, functional analysis and operator theory, stochastic processes, approximation theory, optimization, orthogonal polynomials, systems theory, scattering theory, signal processing, probability, and many more. No wonder that the greatest names in mathematics have contributed to the problem with papers and monographs. Because of the many connections to different fields also many approaches and many generalizations have been considered.
>   ...
>   The fact that today, 100 years after Hamburger and Hausdorff, this is still an active research field is another proof of the importance of moment problems.

From a [review by Adhemar Bultheel](http://euro-math-soc.eu/review/moment-problem) of Schmüdgen's book.